# Function is not defined or not there

Tags: javascript

When i try to rename my keys in the Object, i get function not defined... but its defined and called properly... is there any way we can re write the function and use it...

Answer (score 4):

The function renamekeys should be defined before you call it, also make sure that obj[i] is an object.